# PHP Process XML Data

Tags: mysql, php

I'm writing to read a xml from a wbsite.

```
$jtype = $job_type == 1 ? 'fulltime' : $job_type == 2 ? 'parttime' : $job_type == 3 ? 'contract':'';
    $xml ="http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?";
    $xml .="publisher=9628233567417007";
    $xml .="&q=".$q; //Query. By default terms are ANDed. To see what is possible, use our advanced search page to perform a search and then check the url for the q value.
    $xml .="&l=".$location; //Location. Use a postal code or a "city, state/province/region" combination.
    $xml .="&sort="; //Sort by relevance or date. Default is relevance.
    $xml .="&radius=30"; //Distance from search location ("as the crow flies"). Default is 25.
    $xml .="&st=employer"; //Site type. To show only jobs from job boards use 'jobsite'. For jobs from direct employer websites use 'employer'.
    $xml .="&jt=".$jtype ; //Job type. Allowed values: "fulltime", "parttime", "contract", "internship", "temporary".
    $xml .="&start=0"; //Start results at this result number, beginning with 0. Default is 0.
    $xml .="&limit=10"; //Maximum number of results returned per query. Default is 10
    $xml .="&fromage=".$within; //Number of days back to search.
    $xml .="&filter=1"; //Filter duplicate results. 0 turns off duplicate job filtering. Default is 1.
    $xml .="&latlong=1"; //If latlong=1, returns latitude and longitude information for each job result. Default is 0.
    $xml .="&co=GB";//arch within country specified. Default is us. See below for a complete list of supported countries. 
    $xml .="&v=2";

    $xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml, null, true);
    $xmls = $xmlData->xpath('results/result');

    $jIndeed = array();
    $iIndeed=1;
    if( !empty($xmls) )
    {
        foreach ( $xmls as $xml )
        {
            $created_at = strftime( dateFormat ,strtotime((string)$xml->date));
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['job_id']            = (string)$xml->jobkey;
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['jobTitle']          = cleanText( (string)$xml->jobtitle );
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['var_name']          = seoUrl( (string)$xml->jobtitle);
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['jobDescription']    = (string)$xml->snippet;
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['created_at']        = $created_at;
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['job_type']          = (string)$xml->typeName;
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['companyName']       = (string)$xml->company;
            $jIndeed[$iIndeed]['location']          = (string)$xml->formattedLocation;
            $iIndeed++;
        }
        $smarty->assign('searchIndeed', $jIndeed);
    }
```

When I run this on local machine it works fine but when I upload to my site I get error 500 "Page cannot be display"

I have change the memery to 20MB and chnage the post to 1000 but still failing. I think my host has limit, it does not make any differece when i set in php is still failed,

Does any have xml class I can used to process this website xml.

**UPDATE:**

After Putting this `ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);`

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /.../indeedXMLSearch.php on line 44
>   Warning: SimpleXMLElement::_*construct(http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=9628233567417007&q=desktop&l=&sort=&radius=30&st=employer&jt=&start=0&limit=10&fromage=&filter=1&latlong=1&co=GB&v=2): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /.../indeedXMLSearch.php on line 44
>   Warning: SimpleXMLElement::*_construct(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=9628233567417007&q=desktop&l=&sort=&radius=30&st=employer&jt=&start=0&limit=10&fromage=&filter=1&latlong=1&co=GB&v=2" in /.../indeedXMLSearch.php on line 44 
>   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /.../indeedXMLSearch.php:44 ...

Comment: write ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL); at first line of your code and then run it will show all errors.

Comment: I have added the error i'm geeting now

Comment: You can find more info about your error here : http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php Your host disabled the ability to simply load another URL as a local file. You could try to see if curl is enabled on your host

Comment: @koopajah after adding ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true); it is display. are these safe do so.

Comment: Try using my solution from answers.

Comment: Which PHP 4 version are you using? Obviously you're not using PHP 4, but why did you comment you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security season, php disable fopen url in default setting. You 'd better get xml file content according [php curl lib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) and save it to local file.

Then use `new SimpleXMLElement ($localxml)`.

Example Code:

```
$xml = "http://....";

$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$xmlcontent = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('/tmp/xmlfile', $xmlcontent);
$xmlelement = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml, null, true);
.....
```

Comment: Can I write my own class to do this without using fopen

Comment: $xmlelement = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml, null, true); is still using the orginal xml file

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$xmlData  = simple_xml_load_file(file_get_contents($xml));
print_r($xmlData);
```

instead of

```
 $xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml, null, true);
```

Comment: I'm using php 4 on my host. i through file_get_contents is only in php 5

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function simple_xml_load_file() in

Comment: file_get_contents will also be fail while allow_url_fopen is false.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. corrected function i get this.  Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity